# Weatherlib library not working on android app

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, weather, weather-api

I am trying to implement a weather app using 
 **https://github.com/survivingwithandroid/WeatherLib/**

I'm getting the following error

```
E/AndroidRuntime(20029): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.survivingwithandroid.weather.lib.R$string
E/AndroidRuntime(20029):        at com.survivingwithandroid.weather.lib.WeatherCode.<clinit>(WeatherCode.java:36)
E/AndroidRuntime(20029):        at com.survivingwithandroid.weather.lib.provider.openweathermap.OpenweathermapCodeProvider.getWeatherCode(Openwea
apCodeProvider.java:98)
E/AndroidRuntime(20029):        at com.survivingwithandroid.weather.lib.provider.openweathermap.OpenweathermapProvider.getCurrentCondition(OpenwemapProvider.java:111)
E/AndroidRuntime(20029):        at com.tet.ledeliziedellabrenta.weather.WeatherClientDefault$7.onResponse(WeatherClientDefault.java:411)
E/AndroidRuntime(20029):        at com.tet.ledeliziedellabrenta.weather.WeatherClientDefault$7.onResponse(WeatherClientDefault.java:1)
E/AndroidRuntime(20029):        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
E/AndroidRuntime(20029):        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:1)
```

I've also tried adding string codes in my string files (for every language), coping them from source of lib, nothing changed! Heeeelp please :) thank you

Comment: Can you post the source code you are using so i can give a check?!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem you mentioned is resolved. The source code is available at github.